# Python match dictionary in given list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

good day, I'm having some error with a simple script. I just need to print the list of cars from my list. If anyone can comment, It'll be much appreciated. thanks.

```
mylist = ['mango','apple','tesla','honda']
vdict = {'car':['honda','nissan','tesla'],'fruits':['banana','apple','mango']}
result = None
for vdict in mylist:
    if vdict['car'] == mylist:
        result = vdict
print(str(result))
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Don't just say "here's my code, fix it for me". Include the full error, what you expected to happen, what actually happens, and what you have tried to debug your code. Also read [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953). [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/843953)

Comment: How about: `print(vdict['car']`)?

Comment: can you please provide expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to explain, but your example is a little confusing.

The first mistake you made was assigning the iterated value to a variable of the same name in your `vdict` dictionary.

```
...
vdict = {'car':['honda','nissan','tesla'],'fruits':['banana','apple','mango']}
...
for vdict in mylist:
...
```

When you do this you will go through all the values ​​in the `mylist` list and the value of each iteration will be assigned to `vdict`, thus overwriting your dictionary of the same name.

```
mylist = ['mango','apple','tesla','honda']
vdict = {'car':['honda','nissan','tesla'],'fruits':['banana','apple','mango']}
result = None
# So we will go through your mylist list and assign 
# the value of each iteration to the variable car.
for car in mylist:
    # The code below checks whether the value of car (which is the iterated item) 
    # is contained in the car value key in your dictionary.
    if car in vdict['car']:  # If we use = instead of in, the value contained in car must be identical to the value contained in your dictionary in the car key
        # Below, we assign the value contained in the car key of 
        # your dictionary to the result variable if the above condition is true.
        result = vdict['car']
print(str(result))
```